# Add new column in WebGrid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, webgrid

In my razor view, I have a collection of objects that I want to display in a grid. I am able to do so with all fields but when I want to remove some and add more out of the source (the collection) I get `'Column "DaysLeft" does not exist'`

My code:

@Code

```
ViewData("Title") = "Index"

Dim grid = New WebGrid(source:=Model, defaultSort:="proj_created_time")


Dim ListOfColumns As List(Of WebGridColumn) = New List(Of WebGridColumn)
Dim ProjectTitle As WebGridColumn = grid.Column("project_title")
ProjectTitle.Header = "Title"
Dim ProjectStatus As WebGridColumn = grid.Column("proj_status")
ProjectStatus.Header = "Status"
Dim ProjectInitialDate As WebGridColumn = grid.Column("proj_initial_duedate")
ProjectInitialDate.Header = "Starting Date"
Dim ProjectNewdueDate As WebGridColumn = grid.Column("proj_new_duedate")
ProjectNewdueDate.Header = "Due Date"

Dim DaysLeftCol As New WebGridColumn With {.ColumnName = "DaysLeft", .Header = "DaysLeft"}

ListOfColumns.Add(ProjectTitle)
ListOfColumns.Add(ProjectStatus)
ListOfColumns.Add(ProjectInitialDate)
ListOfColumns.Add(ProjectNewdueDate)
ListOfColumns.Add(DaysLeftCol)
```

End Code

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns:=ListOfColumns, tableStyle:="table")
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was similar to this

```
        Dim ProjectDownload As WebGridColumn = grid.Column(header:="Attachement", columnName:="project_ID", format:=Function(item)
                                                                                                                        If item.project_attachement.count > 0 Then

                                                                                                                            Dim newLink As HtmlString
                                                                                                                            For Each down In item.project_attachement
                                                                                                                                Dim chec = down.project_ID & " " & down.project_atta_name
                                                                                                                                newLink = New HtmlString(helper.ActionLink("Download", "FileDownload", "Project", New With {.id = down.project_ID, .name = down.project_atta_name}).ToString)
                                                                                                                                Return newLink
                                                                                                                            Next

                                                                                                                        Else
                                                                                                                            Return "No File"
                                                                                                                        End If
                                                                                                                    End Function, canSort:=False)
```